# EF4 and Code-First: Why do DDD people like it?

Tags: entity-framework-4, domain-driven-design, code-first

The Queen of Entity Framework [suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg232765.aspx) that EF4 Code-First is really attractive for DDD people.  This statement is also made in many other places.

My question is:  Why is Code-First more attractive than Model-First?  I would have thought that the latter is more in line with the way DDD works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model-First refers to the database model. Code-First refers to the domain model in code.  DDD will often prefer Code-First because the database model is a persistence concern, which always takes a back seat to the code model in DDD.

Comment: But isn't almost always the case that the entities you create in the model designer correspond directly to the tables in the database?  That is, when DDD people create their class diagrams, isn't this the same activity as using the model diagram?

Comment: It doesn't matter that the entities "almost always" correspond directly to database tables.  The whole point is that they don't have to.  The philosophy in DDD is to focus on defining Bounded Context's, Aggregate Roots, etc. - these are all concepts that exist in the code.  Starting with a set of database tables tends to influence how we design the classes, and negatively so.  The idea is to design what you want to work with programmatically - something that can properly encapsulate the domain, and then do what is needed with persistence to meet the other non-functional requirements.

Comment: "Starting with a set of database tables tends to influence how we design the classes, and negatively so."  

Good point, and this could be an entire question in itself.  Maybe I'll start one!

I think I had a misconception about what the function of the model designer really was.  Thank you!